# How to use Xpath in Yahoo! Widgets to traverse a tree?

Tags: xml, xpath, children, yahoo-widgets

I'm creating a **Yahoo! Widget** and have done this before without any problems (creating a widget).
I'm getting a **xml document** via a weblink and want to get all the nodes intro a tree. I'm doing this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open( "GET", url, false );
        request.send();
        if ( request.status == 200 )
        {
            doc = request.responseXML;
            tree = doc.evaluate("/lfm");
            status = tree.item(0).getAttribute("status")
            if(status == "ok")
            {
                print ("status is ok!");
                tracks = doc.evaluate("/lfm/recenttracks[1]/track");
                for(i=0;i<tracks.length;i++)
                {
                    artist = tracks.item(i).firstChild.firstChild.data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This way you can get the node **artist** out of the **tree**. there's a problem though if you want to have the **next sibling**. You have to call

```
tracks.item(i).firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.data;
tracks.item(i).firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.data;
tracks.item(i).firstChild.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.data;
```

to get this done. The node next to that adds a **'nextsibling'** to it and so on. I do not want to keep on adding these nodes and thought it would be possible to use **childNodes[i]** like this:

```
artist = tracks.item(i).childNodes[0].firstChild.data;
nextitem = tracks.item(i).childNodes[1].firstChild.data;
```

this doesn't work though. it returns **"childNodes[0] has no properties"** in whatever way I use it.
Now I think there's also a way in **Xpath** to do this in a for-loop:

```
name = doc.evaluate("string(/lfm/recenttracks[1]/track["+i+"]/name)");
                    print(name);
othernode = doc.evaluate("string(/lfm/recenttracks[1]/track["+i+"]/album)");
                    print(othernode);
```

and then increasing **i** for the next track.
but somehow this returns only **one** item. it doesn't retrieve more items in a **for**-loop. **i-1** doesn't work either.

Anyone knows how to use a Xpath expression with my i value to choose a node and then get the subnodes per supernode? Per **track** I want to get **artist, name, streamable, mbid, album, url, image(small), image(medium), image(large)** and **date.**

my xml file looks like this:

```
<lfm status="ok">
   <recenttracks user="xaddict">
      <track nowplaying="true"> 
         <artist mbid="f5b8ea5f-c269-45dd-9936-1fedf3c56851">The Presets</artist>
         <name>Girl (You Chew My Mind Up)</name>
         <streamable>1</streamable>
         <mbid></mbid>
         <album mbid="b150d099-b0f3-4feb-9a05-34e693c6dd24">Beams</album>
         <url>http://www.last.fm/music/The+Presets/_/Girl+%28You+Chew+My+Mind+Up%29</url>
         <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/8696437.jpg</image>
         <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/8696437.jpg</image>
         <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/8696437.jpg</image>
         <date uts="1236440600">7 Mar 2009, 15:43</date>
      </track>
      <track > 
         <artist mbid="f5b8ea5f-c269-45dd-9936-1fedf3c56851">The Presets</artist>
         <name>Get Outta Here</name>
         <streamable>1</streamable>
         <mbid></mbid>
         <album mbid="0469956f-d895-4120-8ec5-29ad41b9e2fd">Blow Up</album>
         <url>http://www.last.fm/music/The+Presets/_/Get+Outta+Here</url>
         <image size="small">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/20923179.png</image>
         <image size="medium">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/20923179.png</image>
         <image size="large">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/20923179.png</image>
         <date uts="1236440242">7 Mar 2009, 15:37</date>
      </track>
   </recenttracks>
</lfm>
```

Comment: an example of your source xml and what you want to get out of it would help.

Comment: done, see the added xml!

Comment: and, again, what do you want to get out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fully Xpath-enabled way of doing this is using the string conversion in Xpath. Ive already posted this code as an answer to another question and will do this again. I'm very glad I found out about this way of doing things.

```
var entries = xmlDoc.evaluate("lfm/recenttracks/track");
var length = entries.length;
for(var i = 0; i &lt; length; i++) {
   var entry = entries.item(i);
   var obj = {
      artist: entry.evaluate("string(artist)"),
      name: entry.evaluate("string(name)"),
      url: entry.evaluate("string(url)"),
      image: entry.evaluate("string(image[@size='medium'])")
   };
posts[i] = obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 for (var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('track').length; i++)
            {
                alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('track')[i].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
            }
```

---

if you want to use xpath, you can also try the below solution.

```
var s = xmlDoc.evaluate( '//track' ,xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
var track = s.iterateNext();

while (track)
{
     alert(track.getElementsByTagName('name')[0].textContent );
     track = s.iterateNext();
}
```

Comment: I want to use XPath, since it works much faster in Yahoo! Widgets. SO this is not really an option. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, try the seed value as 1 for the xpath index.

Comment: I tried it just now and it seems both codes work in normal javascript but the first returns "TypeError: xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("track")[0] has no properties" in Yahoo! Widgets. The second returns "function s.iterateNext does not exist"

Comment: Can you pls post more details about Yahoo widget. And also are you sure you trying this on a Xml type object and not any custom yahoo type.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the relevant XML fragment?  We're looking at your code that parses it, but if we had the XML itself, it'd be easier to cons up an Xpath query. 
Most useful would be the bit that has elements like

```
<lfm>
    <recenttracks>
        <track>
            <album>
```

etc